# W3 Total Cache stuck in preview mode

Tags: wordpress

When I click deploy button I get that a success message

```
Preview settings successfully deployed.
```

But it still says that I'm in preview mode

```
Preview mode is active: Changed settings will not take effect until preview mode is or . any changed settings (without deploying), or make additional changes.
```

Answer (score 3):

you must click on the Deactivate button, which then gets you out of Preview mode.  I know, it seems counter intuitive to click on something called Deactivate to fully activate the plugin. :)

Comment: It's "disable", at least in the current version.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you’ll need to do is log in to your WordPress dashboard and install the W3 Total Cache plugin. Once you activate it, there will be a new Performance button on the left hand side of the dashboard. Click on that to bring up the options page.

You’ll see a yellow bar at the top of the screen that says “Preview mode is active: Changed settings will not take effect until preview mode is deploy or disable. Click on the disable button.

You can now begin to tweak your settings.
Check the Enable box under the following sections and save your changes:
Page Cache,
Minify,
Database Cache.
Next, click the Minify link at the top. Check the following boxes under the HTML & XML section, then click Save All Settings:
Enable,
Inline CSS minification,
Inline JS minification,
Don’t minify feeds,
Line break removal.
You’re almost done! Click on the Browser Cache link at the top. Check the following boxes under the General section, then Save All Settings:
Set expires header,
Set cache control header,
Set entity tag (eTag),
Do not process 404 errors for static objects with WordPress,

The last thing you’ll need to do is empty the page cache. Just click the button in the yellow bar that appeared as you were adjusting settings.
You’re done setting up the plugin!